# Food stored in a warm freezer

Tags: food-safety

My self-defrosting freezer appears to have gotten stuck in defrost mode for the past three weeks.  The internal temperature is around 25F rather than the ideal 0F, but nothing seems to have thawed.  Is the food still good to eat?

(The refrigerator compartment is also too warm, at 45F rather than 35F, but nothing in there is particularly heat-sensitive.)

Comment: Our main safety question already states: "If your freezer is set at a temperature higher than -18°C (three-star setting), these times may not apply. Especially the safe storage time in one-star freezers (-6°C) is much reduced." There is no way to say more about it in general. You will have to find out for each item what the storage time is at your reduced freezing temperature. There is no way to say about all "it's safe" or "it isn't safe".

Comment: @rumtscho I disagree with marking this question as a duplicate, the OP asked about a very specific temperature, 25F, which you admit the answer to the linked question states that it does not apply to such a temperature. It should be reworded as "How do you find out the storage time for a food at a specific temperature (in my case 25F), if that temperature is not a standard storage temperature for that food?"

Comment: @MHH The specific temperature is not sufficient for an answer, it is a combination of food and temperature. There is not a method to find it out for yourself, you have to read it somewhere. Your proposed rewording will make it a question about resources to learn something, which is also off topic.

Comment: @rumtscho It may be off topic, but it still is not a duplicate

Comment: @MHH in its current wording, it is a duplicate. It asked "Is food kept at 25 F safe" and the duplicate target states that for food kept frozen, but above -18 C, there is no way to make a blanket statement across all foods. So that case is covered in the interval given there, making it a duplicate. If you see this differently, you can cast a reopen vote, or start a Meta discussion.